# How do you call a method of unknown type from another class

Tags: vb.net-2010

VB.NET

Having problem declaring my forms/classes and passing in a method pointer with a single parameter but the parameter is of an unknown Type at compile time.

Is it better to declare and raise Events within FooForm and thus expose required data thru public properties or go with the method I describe below by passing in a sub pointer as a delegate. Either way just for my experience I would like to get this to work.

I tried declaring my form Class with (Of T) and a parameter of Action(Of T), T being the unknown type however I do not know how to invoke the Action parameter to call my method. And in case I want to add other actions later it would be more overhead to have multiple instances or inheritance of my FooForm and thus declare myAction as a specific type as oppose to a generic type.

For e.g.:

```
Class AEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public ReadOnly A As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal A As String)
        Me.A = A
    End Sub
End Class

Class BEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Public ReadOnly B As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal B As String)
        Me.B = B
    End Sub
End Class

Class FooForm(Of T As EventArgs)
    ...
    Private myAction As Action(Of T)

    Public Sub New(myAction As Action(Of T))
        Me.myAction = myAction
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnA_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EvetArgs) Handles btnA.Click
        Dim eA As New AEventArgs("aa")
        Me.myAction(eA)  'This does not compile because eA is not of type T
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnB_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnB.Click
        Dim eB As New BEventArgs("bb")
        Me.myAction(eB)  'This does not compile because eB is not of type T
    End Sub

End Class

Class MainForm
    ...
    Sub AFoo(A As AEventArgs)
       'Do Something with A
    End Sub

    Sub BFoo(B As BEventArgs)
        'Do Somthing with B
    End Sub

    Sub ActionA()
        Dim fooA As New FooForm(Of AEventArgs)(AddressOf AFoo)
        fooA.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Sub ActionB()
        Dim fooB As New FooForm(Of BEventArgs)(AddressOf BFoo)
        fooB.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
   ...
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Too much code. Can you simplify your example to maybe 5 lines? I'm not sure what you are trying to do here...

Comment: @Neolisk in short - How do you call an unknown method of an unknown type from another class? In the example code above MainForm.AFoo is such a method. Is there away to pass my method as a parameter and call it.

Comment: Yes, it's called reflection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(v=vs.110).aspx